# Text View not setting text in Android

Tags: java, android, textview

my problem is that when i try to set the text of service1 and service1Health in my code below, The text is not being set. Any ideas as to why this is happening? service1Name and service1HealthValue both have valid string values.

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{

    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.loginButton:
        String[] values = new String[2];
        String usernameText = ((TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.usernameTextBox)).getText().toString();
        String passwordText = ((TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.txtPasswordField)).getText().toString();

        if (usernameText.length()==0 || passwordText.length()==0)
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Please fill in both username and password fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Connecting to server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String loginResult = Server.login(usernameText,passwordText);

            values = loginResult.split(",");

            Intent i = new Intent(activity,Home.class);
            activity.startActivity(i);
            activity.setContentView(R.layout.home);

            String service1Name = Server.getServices("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
            String service1HealthValue = Server.getHealth("myservice","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");


            TextView service1= ((TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.serviceName1));
            TextView service1Health= ((TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.service1Health));


            service1.setText(service1Name);
            service1Health.setText(service1HealthValue);

        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably won't help, but have you tried to invalidate the TextViews? Have you checked if they are found by the id? Try using Log messages and LogCat or debug to see what's happening.

Comment: By the way you should not perform network operations in a listener, start a new thread or asynctask for that and call back to the GUI thread when you're finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `activity.startActivity(i);`, it launches a new activity, so any code after this, including `activity.setContentView(R.layout.home);` will not be reached, so none of these `TextViews` will get set. If you want to set these values in the new activity, you should add them to the `Intent`, then reopen them in the `onCreate` method of the new `Activity`. So for example, in your current Activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(activity,Home.class);
i.putExtra("service1Name", Server.getServices("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"));
i.putExtra("service1HealthValue", Server.getHealth("myservice","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"));
activity.startActivity(i);
```

And in the onCreate method of `Home.java`, add the following:

```
setContentView(R.layout.home);
Intent i = getIntent();
if (i != null) {
    //This means that the intent passed here was found
    String serviceName1 = i.getStringExtra("serviceName1");
    String service1HealthValue = i.getStringExtra("service1HealthValue");
    TextView service1= ((TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.serviceName1));
    TextView service1Health= ((TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.service1Health));
    service1.setText(service1Name);
    service1Health.setText(service1HealthValue);
}
```